# Security certificate for forums.linuxmint.com

Tags: linux-mint, ssl, https

On forums.linuxmint.com there seems to be on and off problems with the security certificate.  One minute the security certificate seemed to be acceptable and 5 minutes later it wasn't.  For me, it has been on and off like this for the last 24 hours.

I have never run into anything like this before.

There is no issue with my CMOS battery (as far as my computer clock being off).  Is there anything else that I should look into?

I don't notice any issue with other sites.

Comment: I can confirm the certificate for the website is indeed invalid(Edge, Firefox, Chrome, and Chromium Edge).

Answer (score 1):

The problem has nothing to do with clocks.

The certificate is fully valid on its own, but browsers refuse to accept it because it was issued **for a different domain name** than you're trying to visit – it's meant for the main Linux Mint website, not for the forums. Chrome actually tells you so:

[image: (Error text "ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID" from Chrome)]

As does Firefox:

[image: (Error text "Firefox does not trust this site because it uses a certificate that is not valid for forums.linuxmint.com")]

Note that the rejected certificate is quite new (issued yesterday and valid until Dec 2020), meanwhile the actual `www.linuxmint.com` site has a certificate expiring at Jan 2020.

So the most likely conclusion is that the sysadmins ordered a new certificate for the main website, then accidentally deployed it to the wrong web server.

Comment: The certificate that I am told is for `forums.linuxmint.com` is the same certificate for `linuxmint.com` which means they mistakenly deployed a certificate that did not indicate it was for `forums.linuxmint.com`  Edge is indicating the certificate signature is identical for both domains.  Firefox's error message indicates this is the case, your answer is indeed correct, but the certificate expires `Tuesday‎, ‎December‎ ‎8‎, ‎2020 ‎9‎:‎22‎:‎11‎ ‎PM` not Jan 2020.

Comment: I guess they are using a load-balancer, then, with a few backend servers having the new certificate and a few servers having the old one. Most of my direct connection attempts result in a certificate that was `activated '2019-12-09 03:22:11 UTC', expires '2020-12-09 03:22:11 UTC'`.

Comment: **03:22:11 UTC** is **09:22:11 CST**  It's the same certificate, Edge display the expiration, based on the system time apparently.

Comment: I don't automatically know what timezone you live in. Though, regarding "Jan 2020" – that is the _old_ certificate that I get for `www.linuxmint.com` [activated '2019-01-06 14:20:48 UTC', expires '2020-01-06 14:20:48 UTC'], _not_ the new certificate served by `forums.linuxmint.com`.

Answer (score 1):

> ne minute the security certificate seemed to be acceptable and 5 minutes later it wasn't. For me, it has been on and off like this for the last 24 hours.

The certificate is indeed invalid.  I have never been to the site before you submitted this question, and every browser I have attempted to use indicates the certificate is invalid.

> There is no issue with my CMOS battery (as far as my computer clock being off). Is there anything else that I should look into?

The problem is with the certificate, not the client, there is nothing you can do to resolve the error other than ignoring it.

**The certificate is invalid for the domain you are asking about.**

The `subject alternative name` does not include the subdomain `forums.linuxmint.com`

> - Not Critical
> - DNS name=linuxmint.com
> - DNS name=www.linuxmint.com

**The domain is currently only valid for `linuxmint.com` and `www.linuxmint.com`, when you visit the main domain, it does NOT generate an error.**

Answer (score 0):

The certificate just was updated a few days ago.

It might be an issue with cache somewhere between you and the website.

They use Google and CloudFlare caching services, either of these could be having a delay updating their copy of the certificate.  If you encounter a problem hit "reload" up to three (3) times to force an update through the entire cache chain.

As of insuring your system is staying up to date on time, your CMOS clock is not very reliable, and Operating Systems don't use it for more than booting their software clock.  I recommend that instead, you set your system to  synchronize off of a public NTP time server on boot and on a regular basis while booted.  (Every 4-24 hours depending on how accurate you need your time to be.)

Comment: This is unlikely a cache issue.  I have never been to the site, but I am getting a certificate error, and the issue dates are recent (Sunday‎, ‎December‎ ‎8‎, ‎2019 ‎9‎:‎22‎:‎11‎ ‎PM).  **My system time is correct.**